# On-Click Event fires first time, but not subsequent times

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-3.5, onclick

I have a LinkButton which fires an OnClick event to update some Labels; however, after the first firing of OnClick, it won't fire again when I click another (or the same) LinkButton which runs the same OnClick event. (It's a list of people, each a LinkButton, and clicking on one brings up their details)

If I leave the page a few minutes, it will work again, almost as if whatever was preventing OnClick firing timed-out. Of course, this won't be any use to the users!

This is my ASP.NET code for the LinkButtons (encapsulated in a DataList):

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="AdmissionNumber">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Checkbox_CheckedChanged" ViewState="true"/>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_OnClick">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAdmissionNumber" Value='<%# Eval("AdmissionNumber") %>' runat="server"/>
                <asp:Label ID="CalledLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Called") %>' />&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="SurnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Surname") %>' />
            </asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In the Page_Load event in the C# code behind, the following populates the DataList:

```
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataList1.DataSource = reader;
DataList1.DataBind();
connection.Close();
```

And this is the OnClick event:

```
protected void LinkButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton l = (LinkButton)sender;
    HiddenField hfv = (HiddenField)l.Parent.FindControl("hfAdmissionNumber");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=pastonmis01\\inform;Initial Catalog=2009;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("xProcSportNotParticipantDetails",connection))
        {
            connection.Open( );
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionNumber", Int32.Parse(hfv.Value));
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            lTitle.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            lSurname.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            lForename.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            lCalled.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            lDoB.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString().Substring(0,10);
            lSex.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            reader.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

All the connections work, the data is retrieved, etc, so everything except the OnClick firing works. I've done a search of the internet and found this seems to have been a long-standing problem since the first ASP.NET, but there is no solution for ASP.NET 3.5. Does anyone know what causes this, or where I might be going wrong?

Comment: When you click the LinkButton the first time, what is the page doing?  Is it loading, or does it refresh immediately with the changes?  Are any of those controls contained in an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving OnClientClick="Page_BlockSubmit=false" for your link button